# Python localtime,TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: python, typeerror, localtime

I have a DataFrame:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq2H9.png)

I want to the "TimeStamps" show on localtime,but don't running.

```
time.localtime(data_user['TimeStamps'].astype(int))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

How can I do this right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use arrow package

```
from datetime import datetime
import arrow

now = datetime.utcnow()

print(arrow.get(now).to('local').format())
# 2020-04-25 15:55:31+01:00
```

Something like this:

```
def to_local(x):
    return arrow.get(x).to('local').format() 

data_user['TimeStamps']= data_user['TimeStamps'].apply(to_local)
```

Comment: thanks.I have an anwser similar to yours.                                                        
data_user['time'] = data_user['TimeStamps'].apply(lambda t: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(t)))